# Number of ways to cut $n\times n$ board without losing connectivity

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have an $n\times n$ square table. You are to select some "walls" between its cells and remove them. In how many ways can you do that so that the remaining figure would be connected?

Comment: Is it the walls or the squares that should be connected?

Comment: @bof  when n=1 answer is $2^4$. corner points belong to the walls

Comment: @Henrick the squares

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your walls are the connections, so if you cut a wall, the parts adjacent to the wall lose connection?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can interpret this properly. Can you provide more examples than just $n=1$? - Are the walls blocking the connections between cells initially, or are the walls connections being removed? If it is the first case, by connected cells, you mean that you need to remove walls such that you get a valid path of squares that can be walked: visit every square without crossing a wall (and also, you can't leave the boundaries of the table)?